# Get key-value pairs of specific fields from Many-to-many related models without duplication

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to get the keys and values of the specific fields from two models with one queryset. I use a many-to-many relationship between them.

I use this queryset:

```
Article.objects.values('title', 'topic__title')[:9]
```

My models (shotlisted most of the fields for simplicity):

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=99)
    topic  = models.ManyToManyField('Topic', related_name='articles')
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

This queryset returns one Article object multiple times if that Article object has multiple topics. How can I get only specified keys without sacrificing performance (with one query if possible)?

I want queryset to return a list of dicts like this (anything near to it is acceptable as well):

```
[
    {
        "title": "Hello world",
        "topic__title": ["Programming", "Tutorial"]
    },
    {
        "title": "Let's start coding",
        "topic__title": "Tutorial"
    }
]
```

Please provide your code with an explanation and your suggestions are very welcome and highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive all the data you need with `prefetch_related` - it actually will execute two sql-queries. For your case it should look like:

`Article.objects.prefetch_related('topic_set')`

If you want to only get specific fields from both models, you will need to serialize data manually. Here is example

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

# prefetch all topics with only `title` field
prefetch = Prefetch('topic_set', queryset=Topic.objects.only('title'))
# get all articles with only prefetched values and `title` from Article model
queryset = Article.objects.prefetch_related(prefetch).only('title')
# manually serializing data
result = []
for article in queryset:
    row = {}
    row['title'] = article.title
    row['topic_titles'] = [topic.title for topic in article.topic_set.all()]
    result.append(row)
```